# Low Download Speed when mouse is over Window

Tags: c#, wpf, networking, ftp, mouse

I have the following code to download some files from a FTP Server :
EDIT : I've solved the problem using DotNet, a good FTP WPF Library !

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    private byte[] downloadedData;
    string FTPAddress = "ftp://ftp.cluster007.ovh.net";

    double currentBytes;
    double oldBytes;


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //  DispatcherTimer setup
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);


    }

    public static void DoEvents()
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
            new Action(delegate { }));
    }

    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        currentBytes = Dl_ProgressBar.Value;
        Dl_Speed.Content = "Vitesse : " + ((currentBytes - oldBytes) / 1000000).ToString("0.00") + " Mo/s";

        oldBytes = Dl_ProgressBar.Value;

        // Forcing the CommandManager to raise the RequerySuggested event
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }

    private void Dl_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        downloadFile();
    }

    private void downloadFile()
    {

        downloadedData = new byte[0];

        try
        {

            //Create FTP request
            //Note: format is ftp://server.com/file.ext
            FtpWebRequest request = FtpWebRequest.Create(FTPAddress + "/" + filename) as FtpWebRequest;

            //Get the file size first (for progress bar)
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            request.UsePassive = true;
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.KeepAlive = true; //don't close the connection

            int dataLength = (int)request.GetResponse().ContentLength;

            Dl_Status.Content = "Téléchargement en cours...";
            DoEvents();

            //Now get the actual data
            request = FtpWebRequest.Create(FTPAddress + "/" + filename) as FtpWebRequest;
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            request.UsePassive = true;
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.KeepAlive = false; //close the connection when done

            //Set up progress bar
            Dl_ProgressBar.Value = 0;
            Dl_ProgressBar.Maximum = dataLength;

            //Streams
            FtpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse;
            Stream reader = response.GetResponseStream();

            //Download to memory
            //Note: adjust the streams here to download directly to the hard drive
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; //downloads in chuncks
            dispatcherTimer.Start();            
            while (true)
            {
                DoEvents(); //prevent application from crashing
                int bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    //Nothing was read, finished downloading
                    Dl_ProgressBar.Value = Dl_ProgressBar.Maximum;
                    Dl_Percent.Content = "Progression : 100%";

                    DoEvents();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Write the downloaded data
                    memStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                    //Update the progress bar
                    if (Dl_ProgressBar.Value + bytesRead <= Dl_ProgressBar.Maximum)
                    {
                        Dl_ProgressBar.Value += bytesRead;
                        Dl_Percent.Content = "Progression : " + ((Dl_ProgressBar.Value / 1000000000000000) * dataLength).ToString("0.00") + "%";
                        DoEvents();
                    }
                }
            }

            //Convert the downloaded stream to a byte array
            downloadedData = memStream.ToArray();

            //Clean up
            reader.Close();
            memStream.Close();
            response.Close();

            Dl_Status.Content = "Téléchargement terminé";
            DoEvents();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Dl_Status.Content = "Erreur de connexion au FTP";
        }
    }

}
```

My problem is that when I pass the mouse over the window, the download speed is dropping significantly... 
It changes from 3.70Mb/s to 2.20Mb/s.
When I have the mouse out of the window, there's no problem, but when I'm over it, it slows down, particularly when I do some very short movements, the download speed go to 0.20Mb/s.
I've tried to use Threads and Dispatcher but it was the same.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please do not put tags in the title of your post.

Comment: I have a strange feeling that your `DoEvent()` is the cause of your problem. I would suggest to not use the main thread to perform the download, instead look at using `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: @Clemens Hah, I sure did nice catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your specific question, WPF's `Dispatcher` uses a priority queue, and `Input` level events (like those originating from mouse movement) take priority over `Background` level events.  Your `DoEvents()` method periodically drains the message queue of all events with `Background` priority or higher, so when you move the mouse over the window, the queue fills up with input events to process.  This means that `DoEvents` takes longer to return, and more time elapses before you can resume processing the download.

That said, this is a **terrible** way to accomplish a download; you should **never** use this kind of `DoEvents()` hack in WPF; do some research on the `async` and `await` features of C# (or, if that is not an option, `BackgroundWorker`).  You will find many examples on StackOverflow of how to perform asynchronous downloads without having to resort to this sort of `Dispatcher` trickery to keep the UI responsive.